# Fundamental System ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, fundamental-solution

Let $\epsilon>0$. Look at the ODE
\begin{align*}
y'(t)=A(t)y(t),
\end{align*}
with $A\in C(\mathbb R,\mathbb C^{n\times n})$ and $A(t+\epsilon)=A(t), \forall t\in \mathbb R$.
Let $Z\in C^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb C^{n\times n})$ be a Fundamental System of the ODE. Show, that there exists a $B$, so that
\begin{align*}
Z(t+\epsilon)=Z(t)B, t\in \mathbb R
\end{align*}
Does anyone has a idea, how to solve this task?

Comment: Notice that $B=Z(ϵ)$ and show that $Z(t+ϵ)B^{-1}$ is also a fundamental system. Apply uniqueness.

Comment: For the ODE $y'=\sin(x)y(x)$, I have $A(x)=sin(x)$. With $\epsilon=2\pi$,  $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$ and $Z(t)=exp(-\cos(x))$ is a fundamental system, but $Z(t+\epsilon)\neq Z(t)+Z(\epsilon)$ Do I make a mistake?

Comment: Yes, first $Z(t)=\exp(1-\cos(t))$ so that $Z(0)=1$.  And second, $Z(2\pi)=Z(0)=1$, so that indeed $Z(t+2\pi)=Z(t)·Z(2\pi)$.